# Aurelia build fails - cannot find module babel-runtime

Tags: node.js, npm, aurelia

I created an [issue](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/443) at the Aurelia CLI repo, but figured I would ask here just in case. I'm on Windows 7 with node 7.2.1 and npm 4.0.5. The linked issue has details about dependency versions.

When I try to build via `au build` I get the error below. I have tried starting from scratch:

1. Install latest node version using [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) (node 7.2.1)
2. `npm install npm -g` (npm@4.0.5)
3. `npm install aurelia-cli -g` (aurelia-cli@0.23.0)
4. `npm install`
5. `au build`

```
> au build
resolve failed:  { Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.requireRelative.resolve (C:\myworkingdir\node_modules\require-relative\index.js:30:17)
    at resolve (C:\myworkingdir\node_modules\modify-babel-preset\lib\serialize.js:26:26)
    at findAndRemove (C:\myworkingdir\node_modules\modify-babel-preset\lib\serialize.js:83:11)
    at C:\myworkingdir\node_modules\modify-babel-preset\lib\serialize.js:126:13
    at Array.map (native)
    at loadPreset (C:\myworkingdir\node_modules\modify-babel-preset\lib\serialize.js:118:29)
    at module.exports (C:\myworkingdir\node_modules\modify-babel-preset\index.js:95:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\myworkingdir\node_modules\babel-preset-es2015-loose\index.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\myworkingdir\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } babel-runtime
C:\myworkingdir\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:334
        throw e;
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined (While processing preset: "C:\\myworkingdir\\node_modules\\babel-preset-es2015-loose\\index.js")
```

I tried `npm install babel-runtime` explicitly, but that does not work.

Comment: Have you created an aurelia project? `au new` ?

Comment: Yes, I originally created the project via `au new`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit was when I updated to **babel-preset-es2015-loose@8.0.0** (originally Aurelia CLI has it at `^7.0.0`). That project is now [deprecated](https://github.com/bkonkle/babel-preset-es2015-loose) if using **babel-preset-es2015@6.13.0** or above.

Removing **babel-preset-es2015-loose** from `package.json` and using the new `preset` configuration from that link (in `.babelrc` file) allows Aurelia to build again.

## Update

There's a [pull request](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/pull/444) to fix this. Should be accepted soon.